# How to validate required field in reactive forms

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form which contains account number and profile details.

I am able to validate account number field, but i am not able to validate any required field from profile details. I have used `fromgroupName` for `profileContract` I tried searching on google but I didn't find any proper answer. Any help will be appreciated. I have used reactive forms.

```
{
  "accountNO": "123456",
  "profileContract": {
     "businessTypeEnum": "MASTER_ACCOUNT",
     "masterName": "test data",
   }
}
```

JSON data will look like this.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See also [AngularJS Developer Reference - Forms - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)